# Replace word in excel cell using c#

Tags: c#, excel, replace, add-in

I'm developing spellchecker add in for Microsoft excel. I need to replace incorrect word in cell with correct one. I tried replace() method of c#. But it replaces all occurrences of that word even it is part of another word. I just need to replace one word at a time. How to do this. Any idea.

Comment: so, what about `string wrongword = wrongword.Replace(" " + wrongwordstring + " ", rightword);` ?!

Comment: can you share your code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace() why don't you try to use a regular expression with word boundaries?

Here some additional information:
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/

Thanks,
The Macro Guru